# what does it mean by "in the process of being elaborated"?

Tags: meaning

When I ask someone about a list he told me that "it is in the process of being elaborated".

what does it mean by "in the process of being elaborated"?

Comment: That, at the moment this list is being expanded and more detail is being added. See [elabourate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elaborate)

Comment: It probably means that he doesn't speak English natively. It sounds very Indian English to me: it's technically grammatically correct, but it's not the word modern British English speakers would choose.

Comment: @AndyT - could be, but how does that help the OP?

Comment: It could mean a dozen different things.  He could be going through the list and adding more detail, he could be thinking that it's time to actually start working on the list, he could be working through the list and deleting stuff he doesn't want you to see.  It's gobbledygook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Answer:

It "translates" to *"preparing to be* (*further* - optional, depends on contect) *explained"*

## Lengthy Answer:

It is a hard-to-understand complex sentence fragment, for 2 reasons:

1. "in the process of" - is a complex phrase, that in short means a number of things based on context, but in your specific case "preparing"
2. "being explained" - This is a *state of being*, which (fun-fact about the English language:) can't be fully explained, because there is no way to define the terms "state of being," "being," or the verb "to be" in the English language.

However, I will try to outline the basics for you.

Let's start with the first fragment ("in the process of")

The usage of the word "in" here is it's *state-of-being* usage, meaning that it is not used for describing the location something is *in,* but rather what *state of being* it is *in*.

An example of using "in" this way is the sentence:

> He was *in* a ***coma***

where ***coma*** is the state of being

so essentially in that fragment there are 2 *states of being*:

> "the process of being elaborated"

and

> "being elaborated" by-itself

the term "process" in this sentence is being used as a *state of being*, therefore the word "of" which is describing the word "process" will ***likely*** (it doesn't have to) describe it with another *state of being*

Which in the case of the sentence, any fragment starting with the phrase "being" is a *state of being*

I do want to reiterate that I cannot describe the phrase *state of being,* but you can "describe" it with synonyms and examples.

A synonym would be *state of existence* or *state of existing*

Answer (score 2):

> It is in the process of being elaborated

means it is being written or developed currently.

> It is in the process of being elaborated upon

means there is a draft, but additional work is being done currently.

That is literally what these two phrases mean.  However, that sort of non-answer could very well mean that nothing at all has been done yet!